# An alternative test for normality/gaussian distribution for duplicated values

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I have a large data set in R, which is (effectively) one-dimensional and continuous. Caveat - It can be grouped and subdivided by a number of factors.

I have been using data.table to apply `shapiro.test()` across it: however, in the large data set I have run into a snag:

`shapiro.test()` will fail if the groupings contain duplicate values. This is displayed as an error message, and not described well in the documentation. I suspect that this is because Shapiro-Wilk operates by ordering the continuous variable, and that duplicates cause an obvious problem.

The amount of duplicates effectively per subject (largest classification) can range from 1% to 93%. This is largely as the precision of the data is to 1 sf. This cannot be changed.

What alternative can/should I use to test for normal/Gaussian distribution across a single dimensional variable in r? My groupings will have between 6 and 25 observations per group. Arranging all the data in 'long' form to test gives around 17,000,000 rows.

My current solution is to discard any subject with more than a few % of duplicates, discard the duplicates, and re-run. I suspect there is a more sensitive way of dealing with this problem.

Comment: I don't get the main focus here, whether it's on thousands of groups, in which case you need a strategy to cope with all those tests, or on the millions of observations, in which case I expect a very low P-value  regardless of whether your data are (adequately) close to normal for whatever your purpose is. Evidently your variable is continuous in principle but measured so coarsely that it is in practice discrete, or at least granular, for reasons completely beyond your control. EIther way, I would still place most emphasis on plots here in which you can visualise the impact of ties.

Comment: One strategy is to get a handle on your problem by simulating, namely generating normal distributions, rounding to 1 s.f. and then seeing how tests behave.

Comment: @NickCox - the problem is not the repetition, `data.table` handles that well enough for the population, as it does the split-apply-combine process. The stress is on working around the duplicates. Is there an alternative to Shapiro I can use to full fill the req (test for normality), but that is more robust with duplicates, or utilises the duplicates fully.

Comment: If you apply many, many tests you have a problem of multiple comparisons, at its simplest that under the null you must hit the target several times just by chance. Questions here shouldn't pivot on understanding particular software, but my impression from a great distance (I use R about once a year) is that `data.table()` is a useful results aggregation machine, rather than a tool for combining or adjusting P-values. You evidently want a test for normality when the data are coarsened and my one sketchy suggestion remains getting a handle on P-values via simulation.

Comment: It's just terminology, but the word **duplicates** is potentially confusing here. It  leads me to expect multiple entry of the same observations. Here, if I understand you correctly, the problem is just that independent measurements are often reported as the same because of rounding, i.e. there are **ties**. The difference is between Joanna, height 1.8 m, being entered multiply in the same dataset by accident (duplicates), and there being several women with height 1.8 m in a dataset (ties).

Comment: it is in this case ties, yes.